# Custom count on derived table

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

[image]

I have an events table. The above screenshot show a derived result from events table. It basically shows total number of 'x' event fired by a user in a week.

My business logic says, if a user fires more than 5 events in a week then he is an active user in that week. If a user is active in 2 weeks, then he is loyal user.

I want to plot a graph between week and number of loyal users (users who have been active in 2 weeks in past). I am stuck at this derive table. Please help!

Comment: How are the dates actually stored? We could use regex to extract the dates from the string shown but it would be more efficient to start with date values if you have them. Please post table definition and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would consider here is:

- Group By Employee ID, Year, Week [datepart/extract data from date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)
- Having Count >= 5

So something like

```
SELECT Employee FROM Table GROUP BY Employee, datepart('year', Date), datepart('week', DATE) HAVING COUNT(*) >=5
```

To then get all Employees having atleast 2 active weeks is like this

```
SELECT Employee, COUNT(*) as ActiveWeeks FROM (
SELECT Employee, datepart('year', Date), datepart('week', DATE) FROM Table GROUP BY Employee, datepart('year', Date), datepart('week', DATE) HAVING COUNT(*) >=5) as activeWeeks
GROUP BY activeWeeks.Employee HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```